# Is it possible to push real-world, real-time data into Unity?

Tags: unity, graphics-programming

I'm pretty new to this, and I'm having trouble figuring out where to even look.  If there's relevant terminology that'll be google-able, that would be a great help.

Suppose I want to have a monitor in-game that displays the output from a camera that's in the same room as the player.  Are there libraries for grabbing and rendering that data?

Comment: Did your question get cut short?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=webcam+unity

Comment: I removed the half-completed part of the question, but I'm not sure this is a good question for this site as it stands because it asks for, essentially a list of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be with [render textures](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-RenderTexture.html), but that is a Pro feature. If you need it for the free version, there might be a good alternative script somewhere. I've been hunting for months and haven't found anything that great. You could try [scripting one yourself](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.html). If you do, I'm sure many would pay a fair price on the Asset Store so they don't have to buy all of Unity Pro.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to look at is a method to first capture the output of that camera to a JPEG. This could be a program supplied with your camera, or a freeware application from the internet.

After you have a JPEG image, you can simply use Texture2D.LoadImage http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html

This will provide a new image to the texture as often as you call the loadimage method. If fast enough, it will appear as video, instead of screen captures.

Then, apply the texture to a gameobject within your game with something like

```
renderer.material.mainTexture = cameraJPEGtexture;
```